# How to store arguments list to vector?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, variadic-templates, stdvector

How can I store variadic constructor arguments to vector?

Example with my failed tries:

```
class Combo 
{
public:
   template <class... Args>
   Combo(Args... args) 
   {
      // this->keys_.push_back(args...);

      // this->keys_.push_back(args)...;

      // this->keys_.push_back(std::forward<Args>(args...));

      //for (uint8_t arg : args...)
      //  this->keys_.push_back(arg);

      // ???
   }

private:
   std::vector<uint8_t> keys_;
};
```

Comment: [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) Don't make life harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. C++11

```cpp
for(auto &&i: {args...}) keys.push_back(std::move(i));
```

2. C++17

```cpp
(keys.push_back(args), ...);
```

3. Oh, sorry, I've missed the obvious:

```cpp
template<class... Args> Combo(Args... args): keys_{uint8_t(args)...} {}
```

Comment: I'm not sure solution 1 works with perfect forwarding, which the use of `std::forward` implies.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux and where do you see perfect forwarding?

Comment: To be honest I confused another answer with the question. But still, it should be noted that the first solution isn't a general solution because it doesn't allow for perfect forwarding or move-only types.

Comment: In C++11 we can also do something like this: `int temp[] = { 0, (keys.push_back(args), 0)... }; (void)temp;` or just `keys = {args...};`.

Answer (score 5):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) using [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), you might do

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility> // std::forward

class Combo
{
public:
   template <class... Args>
   Combo(Args&&... args) 
   {
      keys_.reserve(sizeof...(Args));  // reserve memory for unwanted reallocation
      (keys_.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
   }

private:
   std::vector<uint8_t> keys_;
};
```

---

However, that will allow one to pass types other than `uint8_t` and for those types which can be implicitly converted to  `uint8_t`, an implicit conversion will take place.

This will not be the desired behaviour. Therefore I would suggest the `static_assert` as follows.

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same_v

template <class... Args>
Combo(Args&&... args)
{
   // to make sure that the args all are of type `uint8_t`
   static_assert((std::is_same_v<uint8_t, Args> && ...), "Args should be uint8_t");

   keys_.reserve(sizeof...(Args));  // reserve some memory for unwanted reallocation
   (keys_.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
}
```

this will give you now an error for the following

```
Combo obj{ 1, 2, 3, 4.f };
//                  ^^^^ --> float
```

Comment: Why not just `keys = {args...};`?

Comment: I guess a compiler will optimize it out. [Take a look](https://godbolt.org/z/an3aqT). I like that `movabs rax, 578437695752307201`. :)

Comment: I wanted to push `1, 2, 3, 4, ...` and the compiler generated just four move instructions. `578437695752307201` is `0x...04030201` is hex. This looks nice. ;) `= {}` is essentially what **bipll** suggested under the third option, I don't think it deserves a separate answer. I upvoted both answers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
template <class... Args>
Combo(Args... args)
{
    (keys_.push_back(args), ...);
}
```

Comment: only available since C++17

Comment: @Jarod42 The question is not tagged with a particular C++ standard, so it is fine to assume the latest.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename... Args>
Combo(Args &&... args): keys_ { std::forward<Args>(args)... } {}
```

Or:

```
Combo(std::initializer_list<uint8_t> keys): keys_(keys) {}
```